# Advantage of Oracle Client and Server being separated

Tags: sql-server, oracle, client

When writing an application that'll work with MS SQL database all we do is just we specify the connection parameters (either hard coded or dynamically). And when we install that application on a machine, we don't care if that machine has the proper tool to make the connection to the MS SQL Server database available.

However, in Oracle things are different. We have to make sure that all the machines that we want to install the app has Oracle Client set up. It will not work otherwise. Now my first question is what advantage does this provide? And the second one is if there's some way to achieve the similar in SQL Server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Realistically, if Oracle owned Windows, the Oracle client would be installed with Windows and the SQL Server client would be a separate install.  It's not a matter of advantages and disadvantages, it's a matter of who owns the stack and can bundle their software with the operating system.

Depending on exactly how you are building your Oracle application, there is a good chance that you can use the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index.html) or the [Oracle thin (type 4) JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) to provide connectivity to the database.  Either of these can be installed by your application without requiring a separate Oracle client install.